# Create AD User from Sharepoint Workflow

Tags: workflow

How can I create an AD user from Sharepoint workflow?
Or is it even possible to create a Sharepoint profile and sync it with AD with Sharepoint workflows?

Comment: You would need to create a custom workflow activity to do this or if on 2013, have a web endpoint you could call that could.

Comment: Adding to what Eric said, you can use System.DirectoryServices in your workflow activity code to create AD user:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384369.aspx

Comment: Create Customer workflow activity that will call powershell script that creates AD User.

Comment: Is it possible to create a Sharepoint user profile and sync it to AD?

Answer (score 1):

You could also call a Powershell script. See this article :
http://ilovesharepoint.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Execute%20PowerShell%20Script%20Action

Comment: This is a beta version and already had some bad experience with beta solutions in our sharepoint environment. Sorry but not a good choice for enterprise system.